# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors in R

Tags: r, analytics, data-science

I was trying to address the missing values in R through the following code

```
  {ds$bmi=ifelse(is.na(ds$bmi), ave(ds$bmi, Fun=function(x) mean(y,na.rm=TRUE)),ds$bmi)}
```

it is giving following error

> Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
>             unique() applies only to vectors

Please help how to address this error

Comment: For a start, you have `function(x)` but then use `y` as your variable!

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve. You should provide minimal reproducible example data. e.g. The details of `ds$bmi` is not know. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. It will help you in asking questions in a better way.

Comment: Thanks got it. this error was due to y only

Comment: It's not `Fun=function(x)`, it's `FUN`, R is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here 'ave' doesn't have any of the "Grouping variables, typically factors, all of the same length as x." as described in ?ave (the ... args).

If the goal is to replace NA's with the mean of bmi, maybe just straight up mean is what you want?

```
hm_rows=10;
ds=data.frame(bmi=runif(hm_rows,0,10))
ds[c(1,2,4,6),"bmi"] <- NA
{ds$bmi=ifelse(is.na(ds$bmi), mean(ds$bmi,na.rm=TRUE),ds$bmi)}
```

Comment: thanks it also worked. error was because of y which i was using in mean (y) while in function i was passing x